# Creating a folder, when saving to Sharepoint in Office Application

Tags: folder, word, web-services

Is it possible for someone to create a subfolder for a folder when saving to SharePoint in an office application.

For example I have included the save screen. Notice the create folder icon is grayed out.
[image]

Comment: Is the ability to create folders enabled on that document library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActiveX control doesn't support a create folder method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454230.aspx

Comment: Trevor, could you elaborate a little more on this. I have to explain why to a co-worker.

Comment: The control used to display the dialog box as you see it does not support the creation of new folders via the dialog box.  Does that help?